# Full GC becoming very frequent

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, performance

I've got a Java webapp running on one tomcat instance. During peak times the webapp serves around 30 pages per second and normally around 15.

My environment is:

```
O/S: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)
RAM: 16GB

server: Tomcat 6.0.20
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_14
JVM options:
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
               -XX:+UseParallelGC
               -Djava.awt.headless=true
               -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"
JAVA_OPTS="-server"
```

After a couple of days of uptime the Full GC starts occurring more frequently and it becomes a serious problem to the application's availability. After a tomcat restart the problem goes away but, of course, returns after 5 to 10 or 30 days (not consistent).

The Full GC log before and after a restart is at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4NtkNXmi

It shows a log before the restart at 6.6 days uptime where the app was suffering because Full GC needed 2.5 seconds and was happening every ~6 secs.

Then it shows a log just after the restart where Full GC only happened every 5-10 minutes.

I've got two dumps using `jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump.hprof PID` when the Full GCs where occurring (I'm not sure whether I got them exactly right when a Full GC was occurring or between 2 Full GCs) and opened them in http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ but didn't get anything useful in Leak Suspects:

- 60MB: 1 instance of "org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl" (I use hibernate with ehcache)
- 80MB: 1,024 instances of "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes" (these are probably the 1024 workers of tomcat)
- 45MB: 37 instances of "net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.impl.MemoryOnlyStore" (these should be my ~37 cache regions in ehcache)

Note that I never get an OutOfMemoryError.

Any ideas on where should I look next?

Comment: If you have 16gb of RAM on the server, why are not use a larger max heap size (-Xmx)?

Comment: I never got an OutOfMemoryError so I thought that since the application can run then it's ok. Also, I've read that giving too much memory to the JVM will make the Full GC slower. Is that true?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior in a testing environment? Perhaps with some load testing. I've debugged behavior like this before, but usually with ALOT of help from a profiler (which will kill your server in a production env).

Comment: well a full GC on a larger heap would take longer because there is more stuff to collect, but experimenting with larger values of the max heap size might show if your app just needs more space in general.

Comment: @pcalcao: I've done so in the past but it's not consistent. On full throttle stress testing with JMeter I had this occur once at 6 days and another time at 20 days(!).

Comment: @matt b: I'll try 2GBs next time and see what happens.

Comment: also @cherouvim have you seen http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html ? might be helpful.

Comment: "I never got an OutOfMemoryError" - not *all* the memory is used but the full GC are occurring because the old generation is full. Allocating more memory will keep objects in the young gen for longer - more likely to get cleaned by a minor collection / less likely to get promoted.

Comment: @symcbean: makes sense. Will try increasing the heap and re-evaluate.

Comment: As I remember eclipse-mat can compare two dumps of one JVM session. This can show you the difference of situation when issue have not been exist yet and situation with often Full GCs.

Comment: @svaor: I'll have a look. Sounds useful. thanks!

Comment: @matt b : That solved it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Lots of new and discarded objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've switched from `-Xmx1024m` to `-Xmx2048m` and the problem went away. I now have 100 days of uptime.

Answer (score 8):

When we had this issue we eventually tracked it down to the young generation being too small. Although we had given plenty of ram the young generation wasn't given it's fair share.

This meant that small garbage collections would happen more frequently and caused some young objects to be moved into the tenured generation meaning more large garbage collections also.

Try using the `-XX:NewRatio` with a fairly low value (say 2 or 3) and see if this helps.

More info can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).

Answer (score 3):

Beside tuning the various options of JVM I would also suggest to upgrade to a newer release of the VM, because later versions have much better tuned garbage collector (also without trying the new experimental one).

Beside that also if it's (partially) true that assigning more ram to JVM could increase the time required to perform GC there is a tradeoff point between using the whole 16 GB of memory and increasing your memory occupation, so you can try double all values, to start

Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Regards

Massimo

Comment: I'll try. But isn't maxperm 512 a bit too much? The tomcat instance only runs 1 application with around 40 persistent (hibernate) entities and no spring framework. No redeployments happen on this tomcat, only shutdown/startup.

Comment: Could be, my suggested parameters were just a simple guess. I would point to updating JVM as a better thing to try, we had similar problems (and other ones too) and they went away when we updated Java to update 27. Latest is update 29 but we had some problems with it.

Comment: Yes, the logs show a PSPermGen of around ~64MB which I guess is the total loaded class size of: JVM, tomcat, libraries and my app. Right?

Answer (score 3):

What might be happening in your case is that you have a lot of objects who live a little longer than NewGen life cycle. If survivor space is too small, they go straight to the OldGen. `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution` could provide some insight. Your NewGen is large enough, so try decreasing `SurvivorRatio`.

also, jconsole will probably provide more visual insight into what happens with your memory, try it.